# Get default zend db adapter in table model

Tags: model, zend-framework2, adapter

How can I get the default db adabter in my table model? I want to use it to create a transaction.

In database.global.php:

```
    return array(
   'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
        ),
    ),
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=cww;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now I would like to have 
 `$this->adapter` in my albumTable.php

I tried to receive it as follow:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Update;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
use Ajax\Model\Album;

class AlbumTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $tableGateway;
    protected $adapter;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        $this->adapter  = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');    
    }
```

But I get the error:

> Fatal error: Class Ajax\Model\AlbumTable contains 2 abstract methods
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods
>   (Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::setServiceLocator,
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::getServiceLocator)
>   in

Answer (score 1):

Add the following functions:

```
public function getServiceLocator() {
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}


public function setServiceLocator(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
    $this->serviceLocator= $serviceLocator;
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$this->$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

However, if you read the getting started [guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html) it explains how to construct `TableGateways` using a service manager factory, passing in the DbAdapter and other parameters like so:

```
'RoleTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Role());
    return new TableGateway('role', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've set the tableGetaway so I used this one by now to get wat I need '$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()'; that was all I needed :) thanks anyway

Comment: I got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\module\Application\src\Application\Model\Signup.php on line 41" .please see my question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319388/calling-adapter-in-model", is your solution suited to my case ?

Comment: You need to set the service locator or your database adapter in to your model class manually. The comments on the questions should provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

use this to create a database adapter:

```
$adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
```

you can use 'db' only as you have created alias. You can also try writing things in locals.php in \autoload\config\local.php.
Now, suppose we want to execute a database query in mySQL:
Create a sql statetment and put in variable $sql.
Now do this:

```
$statement = $adapter->createStatement($sql);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Hope this helps.